# EF Code first set a foreign key with an empty lookup table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem with EF code first migration related to a lookup table and foreign keys. Let's say I have this two classes in my code:

```
public class Test
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, DisplayName("Test type")]
    public TestType TestType { get; set; }
}

public class TestType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`TestType` is a typical lookup table and I usually fill them up in the `Seed()` method:

```
context.TestTypes.AddOrUpdate(
    it => it.Name,
    new TestType() { Name = "Drug" },
    new TestType() { Name = "Educational" },
    new TestType() { Name = "Other" }
);
```

When I create the table with the relationship I get the following migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.TestTypes",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Name = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

AddColumn("dbo.Tests", "TestType_Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
CreateIndex("dbo.Tests", "TestType_Id");
AddForeignKey("dbo.Tests", "TestType_Id", "dbo.TestTypes", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
```

Now, if I perform the migration of course I will get an error since the foreign key cannot be respected given the fact that the lookup table is still empty and the column created does not have a default value.

In **DEVELOPMENT** I am able to solve this by simply creating two migrations, the first one to create the lookup table and the second one to set the foreign key. If I run them separately then the Seed method after the first one will fill the table and I can tweak the column creation to pick up the values from the DB to prefill the column before creating the foreign key, a bit like this:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Tests", "TestType_Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
Sql("UPDATE dbo.Tests SET TestType_Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM dbo.TestTypes)");
CreateIndex("dbo.Tests", "TestType_Id");
AddForeignKey("dbo.Tests", "TestType_Id", "dbo.TestTypes", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
```

Then when I run it everything works.

Now, in **PRODUCTION** I don't have the same luxury, since ALL the migrations are run before the Seed method is run, I will always have the same problem.

I know I could *potentially* run the migrations in stepped order on the production DB as well but that does not really solve the problem... Let's say a colleague of mine updates his working copy and runs the migrations, all will be run in order and he will encounter the error for sure.

Comment: Should TestType not be creating a table as well?

Comment: @Tallmaris did you ever find a good solution for this?

Comment: Not really. I basically have one option of setting `nullable:true` for the new column and then adjust in the future (which is not ideal) or simply add the Seed to the Migration itself, as they are heavily tied to one another.

Comment: Adding the Sql(.....) statements is the key. I've been able to avoid 2 Code First migrations by adding Sql() statements to do INSERT statements to load the lookup table just after the lookup table is created in the Code First migration. Then when the foreign key column is added to the main table, I make sure that it uses the "defaultValue:" parameter to set a default value that I just INSERTed into the lookup table. Right after the AddColumn(....) in the migration, I add another Sql("UPDATE ......") to set the new foreign key column value in the main table that uses the lookup table.

Comment: Thanks @GregBarth, in the end yes, the solution I've been using as well is to populate the lookup table in the migration rather than in the Seed method. Actually by the way EF works, you need to also populate it in the Seed method if you later want to change some of the values (or again, do the changes inside migrations). Luckily the new EF Core seems to be better at handling these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the current state of your database but I would define your models like this

```
public class Test
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("TestType")]
    public int TestTypeId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Test type")]
    public virtual TestType TestType { get; set; }
}

public class TestType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which results in the following migration when the tables don't exist already.  I always find describing the foreign keys explicitly works better.

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Tests",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Title = c.String(nullable: false),
                TestTypeId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.TestTypes", t => t.TestTypeId)
        .Index(t => t.TestTypeId);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.TestTypes",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
}
```

The seed should then work fine as long as the Test table is empty?

Comment: Yep, the problem is that the `Test` table is not empty... Yes I use the same method of setting foreign keys (I don't like the underline default) but the above was just sample code.